# Create temporary file with specific extension and open it in VS Code

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to pipe some output on bash `stdout` into a new temporary file and open this file using VS Code.

The file content might not always be plain text but also could be `yaml` and I want to create the temp file with `yaml` extension so VS Code uses the correct language mode.

I tried this but I end up with a file having the `txt` in VS Code.

```
cat yaml > $(mktemp $TMPDIR$(uuidgen).yaml) | code -
```

`cat yaml` is just an example for a command which might write `yaml` content to `stdout`.

`mktemp --suffix=.yaml` would be the way to go but this isn't supported on macOS.

Comment: `cat > file | pipe` is an ambiguous redirect. Standard output cannot go both to the file and to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
temp=$(mktemp $TMPDIR.XXXXXXXXXXXX.$(uuidgen).yaml) && ls -la > $temp && code $temp
```

Of course there might be better ones and I'm looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```sh
TMPDIR='/tmp' # Give a value to TMPDIR for the purpose of this answer
mktemp "${TMPDIR}/XXXXXXXXXXXX_$(uuidgen).yaml" |
  xargs -n 1 -I {} -- \
    code --file-uri "file://{}"
```

- `mktemp "${TMPDIR}/XXXXXXXXXXXX_$(uuidgen).yaml"`:
  Create the temporary file into `$TMPDIR` with name composed of:

  - 12 random alphanumeric mixed case letters
    replacing the upper_case `X`,
  - followed by underscore `_`,
  - followed by a random UUID generated by the `uuidgen` command,
  - and suffixed by the `.yaml` extension.
- `| xargs -n 1 -I {}`:
  Pass the newly created temporary file name to `xargs`, which will convert it into an argument:

  - `-n 1`: One argument for each command
  - `-I {}`: Replace placeholder string `{}` with the argument
  - `--`: End of the `xargs` options.
- `code --file-uri "file://{}"`:
  `code` is invoked by `xargs`.

  - `--file-uri <uri>` Opens a window with given file uri(s)
  - `"file://{}"`: The uri for the temporary file just created.
    `xargs` will replace `{}` by the temporary file path.